# How to set up testsuite files for execution across environments

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng, testng-eclipse

I have a test suite file that needs ability to be executed from both mvn command line (from Jenkins) as well as on-demand from Eclipse.

The test suite file must have ability to support parameters, ie:

```
<suite name="test run1">
   <parameter name="testEnv" value="dev"></parameter>
   <parameter name="proxyServer" value="x"></parameter>
   <parameter name="proxyPort" value="y"></parameter>
```

If I leave as is, then mvn command line parameters don't work, as the values in the test suite file will override the parameters.  i.e. this will not work:

```
mvn test ... -dtestEnv=E1QA -dproxyServer= -dproxyPort=
```

How can I write the test suite file so it supports both ad-hoc execution from Eclipse and mvn command line execution?

Comment: I must admin I don't understand fully your question, but usually to enable/disable tests configuration property skipTests is used. (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html). Did you tried use it? Did you find any problem?

Comment: How can i maintain a test suite file so that it supports both, ad-hoc execution from Eclipse and mvn command line execution (from Jenkins, for example).

Comment: Are these params being used across tests ?  And you mark all your tests with these params?

Comment: The parameters are being used in the setup() methods , to load specific config properties.  they are not used in the @Test annotations at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on a combination of above answers, I've figured it out.

First remove the hard-coded parameters in the test suite file.

Next, ensure the parameters are supported in the pom file.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <environment>${testEnv}</environment>
                    <environment>${proxyServer}</environment>
                    <environment>${proxyPort}</environment>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Create constants file to contain default values for the parameters

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String DEFAULT_TEST_ENV = "dev";
    public static final String DEFAULT_PROXY_SERVER = "a-dev.phx.com";
    public static final String DEFAULT_PROXY_PORT = "8585";
}
```

In the testNG setup() method, use System.getproperty():

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
protected static void setUp() throws Exception {
    String testEnv = System.getProperty("testEnv", Constants.DEFAULT_TEST_ENV);
    String proxyServer = System.getProperty("proxyServer", Constants.DEFAULT_PROXY_SERVER);
    String proxyPort = System.getProperty("proxyPort", Constants.DEFAULT_PROXY_PORT);

    System.out.println("testEnv: " + testEnv);
    System.out.println("proxyServer: " + proxyServer);
    System.out.println("proxyPort: " + proxyPort);
}
```

I could put the default values in a config file, but for now, constants file seems easiest in its own class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want configurable test property, use @DataProvider instead of hardcoding suite xml.

Provider class:

```
public class EnvProvider {

    @DataProvider(name = "envProvider") 
    public static Object[][] createData() {
        return new Object[][] { new Object[] { 
           System.getProperty("testEnv", "eclipse-default") }
    };
}
```

Test method:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "envProvider", dataProviderClass = EnvProvider.class)
public void myTest(String currentEnv) {
    System.out.println("Current env is : " + currentEnv);
}
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <testEnv>default-pom</testEnv>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <testEnv>${testEnv}</testEnv>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                ...
```

Result from eclipse right click

> Current env is : eclipse-default

Result from **mvn test**

> Current env is : default-pom

Result from **mvn test -DtestEnv=jenkins**

> Current env is : jenkins

References: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders

Comment: while this didn't completely solve my issue, it did provoke thought and get me going in the right direction.  i've added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the suite xml params with system level args if those are available - which would allow you to run from xml as well as from mvn.

All the params are basically assigned to some constant properties to be used across tests.  The properties file is initialized in the onBeforeSuite method of the suite listener something to the effect

```
SuiteList extends SuiteListener{
 public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
    LProperties.loadProperties(suite);
}



//loadProperties implementation
  LProperties{

    public static void  loadProperties(ISuite suite){
        //This can read from a properties file and load properties 
        //or
        // from the suite.getParameter - pick the params you need (reflection or list) and assign to the constants

        //For all the properties, do System.getProperty and override values if found
   }
```

Use LProperties constants in your tests.